# What is the difference between 'one off' and 'one of'?

Tags: word-usage

I do not believe that this is a duplicate question - apologies if others find it so.

I hear frequent usage of the two terms interchangeably depending upon who is speaking when discussing something built that is unique (sometimes called a "point solution").  It doesn't really matter what the 'thing' is that is or has been built.

**EDIT PER COMMENT**

Most frequently I hear it in the Computer industry.

> The code we built for them was a **one-off**

others say

> The code we built for them was a **one-of**

Can anyone clarify the difference?

Comment: ***one-off*** is usually used as a noun meaning "something done, made, or happening only once, not as part of a regular sequence" (https://www.google.com/#q=define%20one%20off). ***One of*** is a quantifier that never occurs without subsequent nominal material. They are nowhere near interchangeable. Can you give some examples of where you've encountered them?

Comment: You're not **hearing** them used interchangeably, unless you're listening exclusively to non-native speakers of English who have developed their own dialect, because they're not pronounced the same. _One-off_ is an idiom and both words are stressed; there is never an object. It means 'sui generis (of its own kind)', i.e, something specially made, once, for one purpose; bespoke manufacturing. _One of_, on the other hand, always has an object, and the _of_ is **never** stressed; it's normal and common and not an idiom. Just a quantifier, as @Silenus points out.

Comment: The others who say "one-of" are probably actually saying "one-off" but are being misheard. Or they have invented their own perverted noun "one-of" and are using it synonymous with "one-off".

Comment: @Silenus This is exactly what I suspected, but as I did not know, I wanted to ask.  I tried to not indicate what I thought - okay, mainly because I didn't want to be wrong!  :)   Also, the issue is NOT one of mishearing....

Comment: @JoeG: Are you sure you're not mishearing? *One-of* and *one-off* can sound very similar. Do these people write "one-of" as well?

Comment: Mis-hearing can often lead people to *think* something is correct over several iterations.  I have had major arguments over someone writing "We should **of** done something" over "We should **have** (or at least apostrophe-ve) done something."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two phrases can **not** be used interchangeably.

**Off** and **of** are two completely different words.

Look them up in the dictionary. While you're at it, look up [**one-off**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20one-off) as well:

> done, made, or happening only once and not repeated.
>
> *"one-off tax deductible donations to charity"*
>
> something done, made, or happening only once, not as part of a regular
>   sequence.
>
> *"the meeting is a one-off"*

**One of** might look and sound similar to **one off**, but that's like saying **ham** and **hamster** can be used interchangeably.

**One of** is simply referring to a specific individual within a group.

> The code we built for them was a 'one-off'

This means that the code you built will only be used for one particular task, will not be reused, will not be revisited, etc.

> The code we built for them was a 'one-of'

This sentence makes no sense. The only way you can use **one of** in this context is something like this:

"The code we built for them was one of many pieces of software we developed last year."

Comment: sorry about that edit. Accidents happen!

Comment: @Silenus Heh, no problem. It took me a second to parse which wording was correct, so I'm with you!

Comment: maybe he meant awanav http://www.meaningfor.com/5/what-does-stand-for/awanav

Comment: @P.Obertelli Or maybe [anawanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salute_Your_Shorts)

Comment: I think the words would more accurately be described as *mostly* different than *completely* so, or just different without casting emphasis upon how different. This because they have an etymological relationship and more importantly have the same literal collocation signification, except with the main difference being which aspects they emphasize. Noah Webster's given definition for [Of](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/of) has more detail on the subject. Yes, their meaning diverges considerably in their purer metaphoric uses, but nevertheless, they retain at least some similarity.

Comment: @Tonepoet I'm not sure how any of that helps the OP, but feel free to post your own answer if you think those details are relevant.

Comment: @KevinWorkman *"This sentence makes no sense"* - I think it does, if you understand it as *"there's only ever been **one of** these"*. I don't mean it's a correct use of one-of, but that's what a non-native speaker could spontaneously and logically think about.